# Obtain a set of unique values from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.6, set-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries in which the dictionaries also contain a list.

I want to generate a `set` of the values of the respective nested lists so that I end up with a set of all of the unique items (in this case, hobbies).

I feel a `set` is perfect for this since it will automatically drop any duplicates, leaving me with a set of all of the unique hobbies.

```
people = [{'name': 'John', 'age': 47, 'hobbies': ['Python', 'cooking', 'reading']},
          {'name': 'Mary', 'age': 16, 'hobbies': ['horses', 'cooking', 'art']},
          {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 14, 'hobbies': ['Python', 'piano', 'cooking']},
          {'name': 'Sally', 'age': 11, 'hobbies': ['biking', 'cooking']},
          {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 54, 'hobbies': ['hiking', 'camping', 'Python', 'chess']},
          {'name': 'Alisa', 'age': 52, 'hobbies': ['camping', 'reading']},
          {'name': 'Megan', 'age': 21, 'hobbies': ['lizards', 'reading']},
          {'name': 'Amanda', 'age': 19, 'hobbies': ['turtles']},
          ]

unique_hobbies = (item for item in people['hobbies'] for hobby in people['hobbies'].items())

print(unique_hobbies)
```

This generates an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

My comprehension is wrong, but I am not sure where. I want to iterate through each dictionary, then iterate through each nested list and update the items into the set, which will drop all duplicates, leaving me with a set of all of the unique hobbies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a set-comprehension:

```
>>> unique_hobbies = {hobby for persondct in people for hobby in persondct['hobbies']}
>>> unique_hobbies
{'horses', 'lizards', 'cooking', 'art', 'biking', 'camping', 'reading', 'piano', 'hiking', 'turtles', 'Python', 'chess'}
```

The problem with your comprehension is that you want to access `people['hobbies']` but `people` is a list and can only index lists with integers or slices. To make it work you need to iterate over you list and then access the `'hobbies'` of each of the subdicts (like I did inside the set-comprehension above).

Comment: This answers my question, but I have a follow up, if I may.  It works, but PyCharm is throwing a warning which I don't get since your comprehension is working.  The warning is:  Expected 'collections.iterable', got 'Union[str, int, List[str]]' instead.

Comment: Not sure what that means because the `'hobbies'` are all `List[str]`. Maybe PyCharm is confusing something with the other dictionary entries (which would be `str` for name and `int` for age).

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

```py
unique_hobbies = set()

for d in people:
    unique_hobbies.update(d['hobbies'])

print(unique_hobbies)
```